# Недочёты в панели добавления кода SO

Tags: дефект, предложение, сниппеты

Первый недочёт в том, что в панели вставки рабочего кода SO в списках добавлены только старые версии всех библиотек и скриптов. Некоторым пользователям, для правильной работы их кода, приходится выполнять множество неудобных действий.

Второй недочёт - это баг с выделением. Когда пользователь вводит много текста в поле, то строки с кодом не совпадают с выделением и самим курсором.

Собственно данный вопрос был поднят, что бы администраторы SO обратили внимание на эту проблему и обновили библиотеки, или даже добавили новые и исправили недочёты. Пожалуйста, отреагируйте на данную проблему и исправьте её.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не уверен что это [meta-tag:дефект]

Comment: @Grundy Исправил, это [meta-tag:предложение] скорей.

Comment: Первый абзац содержит очень обобщённую информацию и размывает смысл вопроса. Вообще весь текст можно было бы сократить вдвое, но добавить скриншот, поясняющий, о какой панели SO вы говорите.

Comment: Потом, что такое "скрипты" в данном контексте? Под библиотеками вы наверное понимаете jQuery и прочие, но это тоже неочевидно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, исправил